# Slick slider append dots to class

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to create multiple slideshows on a layout I am currently building. I'm having a problem when I try to use `appendDots: '.slick-list'` to append dots to the `.slick-list` class because it's a class created by Slick in each slider on the page and adds dots to each of the sliders.

How can I control the dots so that they only appear for this specific slider?

```
 function createSlick(){
    $(".grid-slideshow").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
       slidesToShow: 3,
       slidesToScroll: 1,
       infinite: false,
       dots: true,
       appendDots: '.slick-list'
     });
    }
    createSlick();
    $(window).on( 'resize', createSlick );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try This:-

```
function createSlick(){
    $(".grid-slideshow").each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).not('.slick-initialized').slick({
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: false,
            dots: true,
            appendDots: $(this)
        }); 
    });
}
createSlick();
$(window).on( 'resize', createSlick );
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I have tried this and I've tried `appendDots: $(this).find('.slick-list'),`

Comment: $('.slick-list') is a default functionality of slick slider. By Default, Dots are appended into '.slick-list' div. Please use custom class name which is given by you.

Comment: I can't because this is where I want the dots to be. I have no other class I can call because there is no corrispoding html markup. Slick creates the class `.slick-list` and the markup for it so I have to call on this class name so that my dot's appear in the area I need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[].slice.call(sliders).forEach(function (elem) {
  var counter = $(elem).find('.counter-class');
  var slickElement = $(elem).find('.items-wrapper-class');
  var prev = $(elem).find('.prev-class');
  //...
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).